# r - grep OR after sequence of digits

Tags: r, regex

So, I have a vector `v` containing a sequence of digits followed by an indication of `day` or `week`. I would like to select the sequence with only `day`.

```
v = c('abc_1day', 'abc_2day', 'abc_3day', 'abc_1week', 'abc_2dweek')
```

I thought the `or` condition would work here

```
v[grep('abc_|day', v)]
```

Why it isn't?

Comment: Try `v[grep('abc_\\d+day', v)]` or `grep('abc_\\d+day', v, value=TRUE)`. The `'abc_|day'` pattern matches *either* `abc_` *or* `day`. Since all the items contain `abc_`, you get them all with your current pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use

```
grep('^abc_[0-9]+day$', v, value = TRUE)
#[1] "abc_1day" "abc_2day" "abc_3day"
```

NOTE: This considers the OP's criteria of numbers followed by day at the end of the string and start with 'abc'.

Answer (score 2):

Using `grepl`:

```
v[grepl("day", v)]
```

This assumes that `day` as a token alone is enough to match the entries you want.  If not, you can modify the regex.  To also match a number before `day` you can use:

```
v[grepl("\\d+day", v)]
```

Comment: `\\d+` says "any (at least one) consecutive set of digits." It is equivalent to `[0-9]+`.

Answer (score 1):

The OR condition is matching either `abc_` or `day`.

One option is to use a [`\K`](http://www.regular-expressions.info/keep.html), which satisfies the criteria that only `day` is matched if it is preceeded by `abc_` and the digits:

```
v[grep('abc_[0-9]+\\Kday', v, perl = TRUE)]
[1] "abc_1day" "abc_2day" "abc_3day"
```

This differs from akrun's `grep('^abc_[0-9]+day$', v, value = TRUE)`, which matches the whole string. Notably, a useful advantage of `\K` over [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) is that `\K` can be variable length.